# Generated string to SQL request in snowflake

Tags: sql, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am actually trying to find a solution for my issue. The problem is this one :
A function generate a string, this string is a SQL request, and I want to use snowflake to "read" and execute this SQL request.

Do you have a solution for this kind of problem please ?

I still continue to try to find a solution if I find it I will put it here.

Here is my problem with more information about it.

```
create or replace function var_test(arg1 varchar)   
returns varchar   as   
$$     
'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ENV_EUT.EUT.TABLE_TEST_ALEXIS_' || arg1 || '(a varchar);'   
$$   
;  

SELECT var_test('3') AS num_table;
```

With this request, i get back a table with 1 column and a value in this column :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ENV_EUT.EUT.TABLE_TEST_ALEXIS_3(a varchar);
```

My problem now is I don't succeed to execute the string in this table. Do you see a way to do this please ? Best regards
Thank you all

Comment: How do you want to send this string as SQL to Snowflake? Programmatically via a connector?

Comment: This string is generated by a function, and I want to take this string in order to execute it in snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Snowflake Scripting.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/index.html

You can declare a statement as a variable and execute it.

See also: **execute immediate**

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html

```
-- very simple sproc    
create or replace procedure myprocedure(arg1 string)
  returns varchar
  language sql
  as
  $$
    -- declare variables
    declare
      smt string;
      
    begin
      -- construct statement
      smt := 'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST_ALEXIS_' || arg1 || ' (a varchar)';
      
      -- execute statement
      execute immediate smt;
      
      -- message to return on success
      return 'Successfully executed statement: ' || smt;
      
      -- message to return on exception
      exception
      when statement_error then
      return object_construct('Error type', 'STATEMENT_ERROR',
                            'SQLCODE', sqlcode,
                            'SQLERRM', sqlerrm,
                            'SQLSTATE', sqlstate);
    end;
  $$
  ;

-- call sproc to create table
call myprocedure('TEST');
```

Comment: Thank you for these informations ! Here is my problem with more information about it. 

`create or replace function var_test(arg1 varchar)
  returns varchar
  as
  $$
    'CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ENV_EUT.EUT.TABLE_TEST_ALEXIS_' || arg1 || '(a varchar);'
  $$
  ;
  
  
SELECT var_test('3') AS num_table;`

With this request, i get back a table with 1 column and a value in this column : CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE ENV_EUT.EUT.TABLE_TEST_ALEXIS_3(a varchar);

My problem now is I don't succed to execute the string in this table. Do you see a way to do this please ? 

Best regards

Comment: @Alex I edited my answer above with some sample code using a Snowflake Scripting to make a stored procedure.